# Why do i get this npm Error: Cannot find module '/home/directory' from '/home/directory'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have the following scripts in my package.json file

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "watchify -o js/bundle.js -v -d ."
  }
```

When i run `npm start` inside `/home/directory` i get this error
`Error: Cannot find module '/home/directory' from '/home/directory'`

My directory structure is like

```
-/home/directory
          --package.json
          -js/
             --script1.js
             --script2.js
```

Why am i getting this error?

Comment: Give more info, please. Full content of your package.json, list of files of directory, from which you run *npm start*.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you can pass multiple argument to watchify.
Lets say you remove the flags, you should get something like `"watchify js/bundle.js ."` so watchify might be trying to run for both `js/bundle.js` and `.` (the last one pointing to your current dir which is `home/directory`)

Comment: You're probably right.  It's likely expanding the final period to be the current working directory and then treating it like a module name.